# Is there a way to add a path variable on macOS with a single bundled archive?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

I've got an install4j program which contains 2 launchers, 1 GUI launcher and 1 command line interface launcher.

Currently the program uses a single bundle archive to install on macOS and it would very time consuming to change this. I was wondering if there was any way I could add some sort of path variable or symlink which would allow users to run my CLI launcher anytime from terminal. (The GUI launcher is installed and set up perfectly already!)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the PATH environment variable is not easily possible on macOS and a change like that might not be appreciated by some users.

I would recommend adding symlinks to `/usr/local/bin`, that directly is already in the path. You can do that with "Create a symbolic link" actions.